# Sticky Table Headers JavaScript not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to implement Sticky Table Headers following this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stFcx/1004/

I changed the code to initialize the 'stickyTableHeaders' to apply to the appropriate table:

```
$(function(){
    $(".results-table").stickyTableHeaders();
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="results-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Info</th>
            <th>Address Info</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="light-bottom-border">
            <td>
                <table class="permit-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong class="dark-green">#:</strong> </td>
                        <td><strong>12345</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong class="dark-green">Title:</strong> </td>
                        <td><strong>Project</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong class="dark-green">Status:</strong> </td>
                        <td><strong>Open (10/12/2013)</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="address-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong class="dark-green">Address: </strong></td>
                        <td><strong>123 La Brea Ave Gotham CA, 91234</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong class="dark-green"> #:</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>1234</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="contact-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong class="dark-green">Name: </strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Johnny Barns</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong class="dark-green">Title: </strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Owner</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can tell the plugin is somewhat working as I can see the duplicated header, which is hidden. When I scroll, the duplicated (sticky) header, is still hidden, and thus, does not work. In the working example, the (sticky) header, when scrolling, removed 'display:none' and the original header is hidden.

I do not receive any errors, so I'm unsure what my issue might be.

You can see my issue in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9jj68tk/

Comment: does this works for you? http://jsfiddle.net/8fkzf9aa/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic issue is that the plugin you've selected attaches to the **window's** scroll and resize events, rather than the nearest scrollable parent. If your table is contained within any scrollable element (such as JSFiddle's `<iframe>`), then scrolling the element won't cause the plugin to fire.

Try this: scroll half-way down the table, then resize the browser window. Now you'll see the plugin working.

You have two options: update the plugin to work using the nearest scrollable parent (see line 152 in your JSFiddle) or choose a better plugin.

I've [modified your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9jj68tk/2/) to include JQuery UI and used the scrollParent() function to find the nearest scrollable parent. Looks like it's working now.

Comment: If that's the case, why does the first example work within the JSFiddle, but mine doesn't? I tried removing the parent div tags, and only leaving the table in the fiddle, just like the working example, but still no luck.

Comment: @ericbelldesigns - I've updated your JSFiddle (around line 148) to use the table's scrollable parent rather than the window. Appears to be working now. I'm not going to answer why the other example was working, though - don't have time.

Comment: Ah that last update you added, works perfectly! The scrollParent() fixed my problem in the fiddle, as well as my actual site. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @ericbelldesigns - Note that there are still some problems when you resize the window. You should probably find a better plugin.

Comment: The sizing problem is unfortunate. I think you're right, I will have to go with another plugin. Thank you for your advice and time @JDB.